# Switching from pulseaudio to pipewire deletes my GUI

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, gui, pipewire

I was using the following link as a reference to switch over from pulseaudio to pipewire.
https://gist.github.com/the-spyke/2de98b22ff4f978ebf0650c90e82027e?permalink_comment_id=3976215

The reason I was looking to switch over is that I've been experiencing all kinds of problems with my bluetooth headsets and I read that pipewire resolved a lot of the issues with bluetooth.

```
sudo apt install \
  libspa-0.2-bluetooth \
  pipewire-audio-client-libraries \
  pipewire-media-session- \
  wireplumber
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libspa-0.2-bluetooth : Depends: libspa-0.2-modules (= 0.3.48-1ubuntu1) but 0.3.48-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 pipewire-audio-client-libraries : Depends: pipewire (= 0.3.48-1ubuntu1) but 0.3.48-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                                   Depends: libpipewire-0.3-0 (= 0.3.48-1ubuntu1) but 0.3.48-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Running apt list -a showed the following:

pipewire/now 0.3.48-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,local]

pipewire/jammy 0.3.48-1ubuntu1 amd64

pipewire/jammy 0.3.48-1ubuntu1 i386

sudo apt install pipewire/jammy and installing pipewire's needed packages and configurations seemed to work except it took out my GUI on reboot. I ultimately had to use timeshift to restore to a previous environment. Any ideas as to why this happened?

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo apt update` via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1444357/edit) to your question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to ask/answer this. After adding the jammy upstream PPA for pipewire and rebooting, I also just get terminal (startx didn't work), then a simple `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to follow up as I found how to resolve my above issue:
Had to check additional packages and install with the /jammy option as there were package conflicts. Installing pipewire/jammy removed a number of packages which ended up breaking my gdm3 GUI. Next time I ran sudo apt install pipewire/jammy, I copied the package list that was to be removed and did research on them. This is what followed:

- gdm3 install gdm3/jammy
- gnome-shell  gnome-shell/jammy
- gnome-shell-extension-appindicator Leave alone
- gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng install the /jammy version
- gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock install the /jammy version
- gstreamer1.0-pipewire install /jammy
- ubuntu-desktop /leave alone
- ubuntu-desktop-minimal leave alone
- ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk /jammy
- ubuntu-session leave alone
- update-manager leave alone
- update-notifier leave alone
  Command I ran is as follows:

```
sudo apt install \
pipewire/jammy \
gdm3/jammy \
gnome-shell/jammy \
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng/jammy \
libspa-0.2-bluetooth \
pipewire-audio-client-libraries \
pipewire-media-session- \
wireplumber
```

This fixed my issue with GUI becoming broken and I was able to follow the rest of this guide successfully.

Answer (score 0):

had the same yesterday after running

sudo-apt remove pipewire

after Ubuntu it broke the audio on Ubuntu 22.04.1 after an regular update it somehow installed pipe-wire (which I dpnt want due to XRUN/latency issues with it).

After reboot got the prompt and recovered it with

sudo apt-get install gnome.

Then needed to reconfigure the whole GNOME settings because they went back to default, such as disabling the annoying auto hide of the launchbar, which option could only be found in settings after

sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock

and then making the dock behavior changes in settings